# Sql query reading more than one row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with stored the availability of tools for each day.
This is the structure

```
    |   Tool_ID  |     Date         |   Available   |
---------------------------------------
    |    1       |     20180501     |       1         |
    |    1       |     20180502     |       3         |
    |    1       |     20180503     |       1         |
    |    2       |     20180501     |       1         |
    |    2       |     20180502     |       0         |
    |    2       |     20180503     |       2         |
```

we can suppose **toolID** 1 is an hammer and **toolID** 2 is an anvil.

I would like to find out, without doing a while, is if tools are available for these 3 days.
For example at least 1 **toolID**=1, the hammer, is available in the meanwhile no anvil is available on May 2nd.

There is a way to find this out just in the SQL query?

Comment: What result set do you want?

Comment: Could you add the expected data in a tabular format as the sample data?

Comment: Learn how to ask question!!!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Well, `group by` and `min()` come to mind:

```
select tool_id,
       (case when count(*) < 3 then 0
             else min(available)
        end) as min_available_for_all_three_days
from tools t
where date >= '20180501' and date < '20180504'
group by tool_id;
```

This assumes that if a row is missing, the tool is not available.

Answer (score 0):

```
select tool_id from
(
select tool_id,date,sum(available) as tot_avl_on_day from tools
group by tool_id,date
)t
where tot_avl_on_day=0;
```

This will check for any number of days and if a tool is available on all the days.

Answer (score 0):

```
select IF(
    (select count(*) 
     from tools 
     where (date >= '20180501' and date <= '20180503')
         and tool_id = 1 and available > 0
    ) = 3,
    (
        (select count(*) 
         from tools 
         where (date >= '20180501' and date <= '20180503')
             and tool_id = 2 and available > 0
        ) = 3,
        "Yes all the tools are available",
        "Tool 2 not available"
    ),

    "Tool 1 not available"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This matches up the number of days available to the number of days in the date range. You may have to CAST your date values to a date type.

```
SELECT
    `Tool_ID`,
    SUM(IF(`Available` > 0,1,0)) as `daysAvailable`
FROM `Tools`
WHERE `Sate` BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-03'
    AND `daysAvailable` = DATEDIFF('2018-05-03','2018-05-01');
```